# Building a server to host rails app locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, server

I want to know how to build a rails server and host an app on it locally. I know I can use heroku or aws but in the case of this app I can’t, the database should be hosted locally in the company for security reasons; they do not want to store their data on servers that are not theirs.

- How do I start?
- What are the main things to consider?
- Do I host on heroku and link the local database to the site or do I host them all in the same place?
- How much power does the machine need for around 10-20k users?
- What OS should I use Ubuntu or what?

Would really appreciate if you have any tutorials or article links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It doesn't require any side server deployments.

Comment: And how much traffic can it handle?

Comment: Research the docs. I've used it for development/staging purposes. Can't say re the production.